# CSS Modules export CSSes as <style> tag in head tag with disabled sourceMap

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, css-modules, react-helmet

I'm writing a `React`, `Server Side Rendering`, `Router4`, `Helmet`, `CSS Modules` boilerplate, everything is awesome but one thing hurts my soul:

At first see my `webpack.production.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const StatsPlugin = require('stats-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const distDir = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
const srcDir = path.join(__dirname);

module.exports = [
    {
        name: 'client',
        target: 'web',
        entry: `${srcDir}/client.jsx`,
        output: {
            path: distDir,
            filename: 'client.js',
            publicPath: distDir,
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'style-loader',
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                modules: true,
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                localIdentName: '[hash:base64:10]',
                                sourceMap: false,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: '"production"'
                }
            }),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(distDir),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compress: {
                    warnings: false,
                    screw_ie8: true,
                    drop_console: true,
                    drop_debugger: true
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'server',
        target: 'node',
        entry: `${srcDir}/server.jsx`,
        output: {
            path: distDir,
            filename: 'server.js',
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
            publicPath: distDir,
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: "isomorphic-style-loader",
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader',
                                options: {
                                    modules: true,
                                    importLoaders: 1,
                                    localIdentName: '[hash:base64:10]',
                                    sourceMap: false
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                loader: 'sass-loader'
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                }
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: 'styles.css',
                allChunks: true
            }),
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
                cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }
            }),
            new StatsPlugin('stats.json', {
                chunkModules: true,
                modules: true,
                chunks: true,
                exclude: [/node_modules[\\\/]react/],
            }),
        ]
    }
];
```

And this is my `template.js` file that server use this for building basic `HTML`:

```
export default ({ markup, helmet }) => {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html ${helmet.htmlAttributes.toString()}>
                <head>
                    ${helmet.title.toString()}
                    ${helmet.meta.toString()}
                    ${helmet.link.toString()}
                </head>
                <body ${helmet.bodyAttributes.toString()}>
                    <div id="root">${markup}</div>
                    <script src="/dist/client.js" async></script>
                </body>
            </html>`;
};
```

Just like I write, I set `sourceMap` to `false`, so all styles loaded as `<style>` tag inside `<head>` tag.

[image: Shitty Loading CSS as style tag inside head tag because of setting sourceMaps to false]

If I set the `soureMap` to `true`, the `<link>` tag appears inside `<head>` tag, Even it is not server side, and has a weird blob url for loading `CSS`:

[image: Results after setting sourceMaps to true]

In fact I wanna server side link tag inside head tag with direct pointing to `styles.css`, how I can do it ?

My whole project is in [**`THIS LINK`**](https://github.com/amerllica/react-server-render-example/)

It has not very lot codes, little and simple, it is just a simple boilerplate. *take a look*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For production builds,inside `client` config, you don't use the style loader. You need to use the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` instead. You did it correctly in your `server` build config. But this config shouldn't be in your server build, as in the server's source code, you never use (s)css files.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
     fallback: 'style-loader',
     use: [
        {
           loader: 'css-loader',
           options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[hash:base64:10]',
           }
        },
        {
           loader: 'sass-loader'
        }
     ]
  })
}
...
plugins: [
   new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css'
   }),
]
```

Add this to your `client` build config.

```
link={[{rel: "stylesheet", href: "/dist/styles.css"}]}
```

And add a `link` props to your `App.jsx` to load a `<link>` tag inside your `<head>` tag.

So your `App.jsx` render methode became:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Helmet
                    htmlAttributes={{lang: "en", amp: undefined}} // amp takes no value
                    titleTemplate="%s | React App"
                    titleAttributes={{itemprop: "name", lang: "en"}}
                    meta={[
                        {name: "description", content: "Server side rendering example"},
                        {name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"},
                    ]}
                    link={[{rel: "stylesheet", href: "/dist/styles.css"}]}/*ADD THIS*/
                />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Your client build config builds/bundles everything need for frontend. JS, CSS, Images, ... and puts this to dist folder.

Your server only serves this dist folder from root /. That's the only thing your server does (besides providing an api for example)

Comment: OK, I got it, your mean is I must use `ExtractTextPlugin` in `client` to omit `<style>` tag and I add a `link` `props` of `helmet` in my `App.jsx` to add `<link>` tag in `<head>` tag. exactly my desire fired. thanks.

Comment: Yes. you could also additionally use the html-webpack-plugin. Then, a html file with proper links to your styles.css and your javascript file will be automatically created!

Comment: Thanks, in this case I guess it is not needed to be use `html-webpack-plugin`, But it is a good guidance for other projects, thanks a lot.